# Checkbox dinâmico não aparece a seta de checado

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um checkbox que mesmo selecionado não aparece o item de checado. Este atributo é criado dinamicamente. Veja a imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando clicado ele teria que estar selecionado assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código quando eu clico no checkbox:

```
$(document).on("click",".preco-prod-adicional",function(e)
{
  e.preventDefault();

  if ($(this).attr('checked') == 'checked')
  {
    alert('selecionado');
    $(this).attr('checked',true);
    var precoproduto = "";
    var valortotal = "";
    var subtotal = 0;
    var resultadoitem = "";
    var replacetotal = "";

    precoproduto = $(this).val();
    valortotal = $(".total-v .v-lor").text();
    subtotal = somarValorTotal(precoproduto, valortotal);
    replacetotal = subtotal.replace(',','.');
    resultadoitem = $(".right-imagem .valor-total .total-v .v-lor").html(replacetotal);
  }
  else
  {
      $(this).attr('checked',false);
  }

});
```

HTML da checkbox:

```
<input type='checkbox' class='preco-prod-adicional' name='checkadicional' value='" + precoprodadicional[0] + "' id='" + prodadicional[i] + "'/>
```

Comment: Adiciona o html do checkbox também, por gentileza. E pq você marca checked quando já testou e o elemento é checked?

Comment: <input type='checkbox' class='preco-prod-adicional' name='checkadicional' value='" + precoprodadicional[0] + "' id='" + prodadicional[i] + "'/>

Comment: Eu ponho porque ele não aparece o checked quando checa. Ele é criado dinamicamente. Muito estranho!

Comment: Tu tá usando estilo comum ou algum outro estilo diferentão?

Comment: Não. Ele esta´em um modal sendo criado dinamicamente pela seguinte variável:   mostraAdicional +=

Comment: Porquê mudar o estado da `checkbox` no click ?  uma `checkbox` já muda de estado por defeito quando se clica

Answer (score 0):

Se a ideia é fazer algo quando ele fica `checked` ou `unchecked`, melhor será utilizar o evento `change` e verificar o estado de `checked` com `.is(":checked")`

Exemplo:

```js
$(".preco-prod-adicional").change(function(){
  
  if ($(this).is(":checked"))
  {
    //código para quando está checked
    console.log("Está checked");
  }
  else
  {
    //código para quando não está checked
    console.log("Não esta checked");
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='checkbox' class='preco-prod-adicional' name='checkadicional' value='" + precoprodadicional[0] + "' id='" + prodadicional[i] + "'/>
```